# HTML Button onclick function()

Tags: raspbian, gpio, java, node.js, mysql

I would like to seek help on my Web Control Interface - LED On and OFF button REST API. I just started node.js two weeks ago and manage to created a basic REST API. It manage to display mySQL database records without any problems and I just created a button with the function of controlling GPIO directly and store to mySQL database. But when I start to run my app.js and click my ON button, my Red LED didn't light up and can't store to mySQL database.

Hope you guys could help me out with it as soon as possible, thanks in advance, guys.

**This is my Button REST API main page screenshot:**

[image]

**This is my app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();

// View engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', index);

// Catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

**This is my /routes/index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var gpio = require('pi-gpio');

var conn = {
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'user',
   password: 'password',
   database: 'rest_api',
   port: '3306'
};

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   var connection = mysql.createConnection(conn);
   var query ='SELECT sensorId, sensor, pinNo, sensorType FROM sensorInfo';

   connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err) {
         throw err;
      }
      console.log(rows);
          res.render('index', { 
         title: 'Sensor Rest API', 
         data: rows
      });    
   });

});

router.post('pin7On', function() {
   var pin = req.params.pin;
   var connection = mysql.createConnection(conn);

   gpio.open(7, 'output', function(err) {
      gpio.write(7, 1, function(err) {
         connection.query('INSERT INTO sensorLog(sensorId, logTime, sensorValue) VALUES(1, current_timestamp(), 1)', function(err) {
            if (err) {
               throw err;
            } else {
               console.log("Successfully store to mySQL database");
            }
         });
         gpio.close(7);
      });
   });
});

router.post('pin7Off', function() {
   var pin = req.params.pin;
   var connection = mysql.createConnection(conn);

   gpio.open(7, 'output', function(err) {
      gpio.write(7, 0, function(err) {
         connection.query('INSERT INTO sensorLog(sensorId, logTime, sensorValue) VALUES(1, current_timestamp(), 0)', function(err) {
            if (err) {
               throw err;
            } else {
               console.log("Successfully store to mySQL database");
            }
         });
         gpio.close(7);
      });
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**This is my /views/index.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 align="center">
   <%= title %>
    </h1>
    <h3 align="center">
   Sensor Information Log
    </h3>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
   <tr>
        <th>Sensor ID</th>
        <th>Sensor</th>
        <th>Pin Number</th>
        <th>Sensor Type</th>
   </tr>
   <% for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
      <tr align="center">
           <td><%= data[i].sensorId%></td>
           <td><%= data[i].sensor%></td>
           <td><%= data[i].pinNo%></td>
           <td><%= data[i].sensorType%></td>
      </tr>
   <% } %>
     </table>
     <br/>
     <h3 align="center">
   Web Control Interaface
     </h3>
     <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
   <tr>
        <th>Sensor</th>
        <th colspan="2">Control</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>Red LED</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="pin7On" value="ON"></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="pin7Off" value="OFF"></td>
   </tr>
     </table>
     <script>
   $('#pin7On').click(function() {
          $.ajax({
              pin7On,
              method: 'POST'
          });
   });
   $('#pin7Off').click(function() {
          $.ajax({
              pin7Off,
              method: 'POST'
          });
   });
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you running node as root? "sudo node myprog.js"

Comment: Nope, rob. I running as pi and just node app.js, rob

Comment: have you tried it with sudo?

Comment: What is the console output? Also, have you [installed gpio-admin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pi-gpio#installation). That is the preferred method. You shouldn't run `node` as root.

Comment: rob: I tried already but still light up and can't store to mySQL database. Gerben: I never install gpio-admin and I'm running as pi instead of root.

Comment: I just install gpio-admin and run it again but still can't works, Gerben.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work, exactly? What did you try? Have you done any debugging, and what was the result of that? What does the javascript code look like on the console in your browser?

Comment: When I click my ON button, it didn't switch on my LED. Yes, but there is no error. Show none, Bex